# Javascript event on other element

Tags: javascript

On one element, is it possible to "subscribe" or listen for events on another element?

I have googled and checked SO, but no luck. I know no such event exist, but is there some clever hack or work around perhaps?...

pseudo code would be:

```
elementA.addEventListener("click on elementB", myScript);
```

edit:
resolved. tanks everyone, i think i didnt explain properly. the way to do it is using proxy objects.

Comment: An event is going down the element's hierarchy, hits the target, then bubbles up to the root of the page, so you can listen for an event on, for instance, a container. The document/window can listen for everything that happens inside it. If ElementA and ElementB are not related at all by any hierarchy, it is probably not a good pattern and you probably don't need to add this kind of listeners. What is your use case actually?

Comment: Why not listen for the click on elementB and then execute myScript in there?  `elementB.addEventListener("click", myScript);`

Comment: This is possible but I don't understand why you would need to do this.

Comment: I'm assuming OP wants a reference to A in the handler on B.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you can try the following:

```
elementA.onclick = () =>{
    console.log('elementA clicked');
}

elementB.onclick = () => {
    elementA.click();
}
```

or modify it accordingly with `element.on()`:

```
elementA.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('elementA clicked')
})

elementB.addEventListener('click', () => {
    elementA.click()
})
```

Comment: this is kind of what i want, but i want to listen/subscribe for the event on element B, not having to hard code it myself each time.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have element A and you want a handler function to have access to it when the handler fires on element B. There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

```
const elemB = document.querySelector('#B');
elemB.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const elemA = document.querySelector('#A');
  // do something with elemA
});
```

This is a ok solution if elemA is dynamically created/destroyed. A better solution if A is going to be around for a long time:

```
const elemA = document.querySelector('#A');
const handlerFactory = a => evt => {
  // do stuff with a
};
elemB.addEventListener('click', handlerFactory(elemA));
```

Now the handler logic can be reused with multiple elements and/or multiple event types.